# Semantic Versioning on multiple services in the same Github repository using GH Actions

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd, semantic-versioning, git-tag

Our team uses a mono-repo, with several microservices, and some common packages between them.

I am tasked with adding CI/CD automation, and traditionally I rely in Git tags for the sem-ver and utilize comments to decide on major/minor/patch.  The [semantic-release](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release) node library does an good job of automating this.

The problem here is that it is a mono-repo and thus commits and tags are only useful across a global sem-ver.  However in my case I have multiple microservices that each will have their own sem-ver.

One thought I have is maintaining a json manifest to store the versions of the services. By blocking direct pushes to the main branch, I can guarentee this file would not be changed on master except by the CI/CD actions.

I also would like to get some ideas from the community on what they would do in this situation? Or what they have done similar to this in the past?

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. What do you want to automate? Why do you want separate versions when everything is in one repo? Why would CI/CD actions change the version? Especially with semver you need a human to decide what kind of version change you need, don't you?

Comment: I came here as I have exactly the same scenario.  What resources did you find useful and/or what did you end up doing?  I don't want API A to change the version of API B when the code of API B hasn't been touched.

Comment: @DorothyHawley fortunately for me I left the project very shortly after that, and moved on to a better one.  My apologies but I don't have anything that would be helpful to you